# command 'md5sum' without '-'token at the end

Tags: linux, bash, hash, command-line, md5

i want to hash the content of an textfile with md5 in a new seperate textfile. And this for each line. I wrote the following bash-script for this

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do echo -n $line|md5sum; done < $1 > $1.hash
```

This works fine. But with

```
echo -n 'somewords' | md5sum
```

my output is something like this `8bf1072ac725ca3bc7f532079dd973ba  -`
And i want my output without the - at the end. So my script should give me something like this:

```
hash 1
hash 2
hash 3
```

and not

```
hash 1  -
hash 2  -
hash 3  -
```

Comment: Just pipe through `cut`: `while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s' "$line" | md5sum; done < "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1 > "$1.hash"`. Or `awk`. For efficiency, put the `cut`/`awk`/whatever _after_ the `done` keyword, like I showed you. And use more quotes. And use `printf` instead of `echo -n`.

Comment: Great, works fine. And also thanks for the printf tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since md5 hashes are exactly 32 bytes long, cut the lines there:

```
while read line; do echo -n "$line"|md5sum; done < $1 |cut -c1-32 > $1.hash
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one answered with `awk`.

```
echo "abc" | md5sum | awk -F "-" '{print $1}'
```

For your example, it would look something like this

```
while read line
do 
    echo -n "$line" | md5sum; 
done < $1 |awk -F "-" '{print $1}' > $1.hash
```

Comment: Actually, you do know. MD5 sums are 128 bits long (32 hex characters) by definition.

Comment: I stand corrected. I will update my answer. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can filter output by `grep`, e.g.

```
printf somewords | md5sum | grep -o '^\S\+'
```

so the script would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
  printf "%s" $line | md5sum;
done < "$1" | grep -o '^\S\+' > "$1".hash
```